# Форма в модальном окне

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте.

На странице есть модальное окно, которое содержит форму, а всю оставшуюся часть страницы затемняет. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на тень форма скрывалась, но у меня форма скрывается даже при нажатии на дочерние элементы `<input>`, хотя такого не должно быть

пример http://jsfiddle.net/qf6dywkx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

Делаем родительский `div` для формы и вызываем `stopPropagation()`

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/qf6dywkx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/2euwxdae/)

Всё очень просто: когда вы кликаете на элемент, он "баблится" на верхний [кэтчер](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126471/). Чтобы избежать - достаточно сверить в методе целевой элемент, и кликнутый.

```
function(event){
  if(event.target == event.currentTarget){
    toggleShaddow();
  }
}
```

И исправил за Вас названия методов и элементов. Так правильнее.

Comment: Если между тенью и формой будут другие невидимые блоки, то тень не будет пропадать (событие click не дойдет до тени). Такая схема часто используется в Bootstrap
Пример: http://www.bootply.com/PurZPHfUOg
Если нажимать слева/справа от формы, то форма не исчезает, потому что натыкается на невидимые div.row, div.container. Нажатия выше/ниже формы работают как ожидается.
Спасибо за ссылку на статью.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал отдельно затенение и поверх него уже div с данными.